# SQL Server Row_number in odd/even number?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, union

I have a question about querying accounting data.

For example, the sample data is show like below

Table: **Table_Test**

```
Date        Amount  
2013-01-01  12.00
2013-01-02  13.00
```

The output should be like this:

```
Date        Account        Debit    Credit
2013-01-01  Abccompany     12.00
2013-01-01  Vendorcompany           12.00
2013-01-02  Abccompany     13.00
2013-01-02  Vendorcompany           13.00
```

Initially, I was think about using a union statement because may be the output sequece is not very important and the sample sql show like below

```
Select 
    Date as 'Date', 
    'Abccompany' as 'Account', 
    Amount as 'Debit', 
    '0' as credit
from Table_Test

union

select
    Date as 'Date', 
    'VendorCompany' as 'Account', 
    '0' as 'Debit', 
    Amount  as credit
from Table_Test
```

Output:

```
Date        Account        Debit    Credit
2013-01-01  Abccompany     12.00
2013-01-02  Abccompany     13.00
2013-01-01  Vendorcompany           12.00
2013-01-02  Vendorcompany           13.00
```

but it seem after I show the output to my PIC, he mention it was wrong that the sequence is quite important to them.(used to export into their system)

What came out from my mind is using T-Sql to manipulate this that may be provide a flag like IsDebit and possible row_number(odd number in first sql, even number on second sql then union and made some logic on it? Possible?)

Is someone are able to provide me some idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Select 
Date as 'Date', 'Abccompany' as 'Account', Amount as 'Debit', '0' as credit,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) * 2 as rn
from Table_Test
union all
Date as 'Date', 'VendorCompany' as 'Account', '0' as 'Debit', Amount  as credit,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) * 2 + 1
from Table_Test
ORDER BY rn
```

Although more columns may be needed in the `ORDER BY` clauses to make things unambiguous (it's a tad tricky to tell with the limited example you've given)

I've also switched to using `UNION ALL` since the result sets produced are already distinct.

Comment: I tried with it, thanks
but the second query the row_number() Over (order by date) * 2 +1 should be -1.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this in your select:

```
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Abccompany ASC))
```